# Нужна помощь с реализацией алгоритма Габова для нахождения кратчайших путей с помощью масштабирования

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Нужна помощь с написанием программы на С++, а именно алгоритма Габова нахождения кратчайших путей с помощью масштабирования. Вся сложность в том, что на русском языке информации про этот алгоритм очень мало(Кормен, Алгоритмы: построение и анализ, изд.3, с 718 - единственное упоминание). Пробовал искать на англоязычных сайтах, нашёл псевдокод, но с реализацией проблема.Ссылка на сайт с псевдокодом -  https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b4db/ebb43dbe4fd261a32f80f86f2f98b246a2eb.pdf

Вот мой нерабочий код, сделанный с псевдокода:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include<functional>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int n;
int maxW(int** g)
{
    int max = g[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (g[i][j] > max)
            {
                max = g[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
void Gabow(int s, int** G)
{
    vector <int> dist(n,INT_MAX);
    int w = log2(maxW(G));
    priority_queue <int, vector <int>, greater <int> > q;
    dist[s] = 0;
    q.push(dist[s]);
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        int u = q.top();
        q.pop();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (G[i][j] != 0)
                {
                    int wi = G[i][j] >> w;
                    if (dist[j] > u + wi)
                    {
                        dist[j] = u + wi;
                        q.push(dist[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while (w > 0)
    {
        w--;
        vector <int> extradist(n, INT_MAX);
        extradist[s] = 0;
        priority_queue <pair<int,int>,vector<pair<int,int>>,greater<pair<int,int>> > q;
        q.push(make_pair(extradist[s],dist[s]));
        while (!q.empty())
        {
            pair<int,int> u = q.top();
            q.pop();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if (G[i][j] != 0)
                    {
                        int wi = G[i][j] >> w;
                        int l = wi + 2 * (u.second - dist[j]);
                        if (extradist[j] > u.first + l)
                        {
                            extradist[j] = u.first + l;
                            q.push(make_pair(extradist[j],dist[j]));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (dist[i] < INT_MAX)
            {
                dist[i] = 2 * dist[i] + extradist[i];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << dist[i] << " ";
    }
}
int main()
{
    ifstream infile("graph.txt");
    infile >> n;
    int** mas = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mas[i] = new int[n];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            infile >> mas[i][j];
        }
    }
    int start = 0;
    Gabow(start,mas);
    infile.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        delete[]mas[i];
    }
    delete[]mas;
    return 0;
}
```

Пример входных данных (матрица смежности):

```
4
0 2 0 0
0 0 1 9
6 0 0 3 
0 0 0 0
```

Вывод алгоритма: `0 2 1 3`
Правильный вывод: `0 3 4 7`

Comment: Так а в чем с реализацией проблема?

Comment: Сижу уже два дня с ним, никак не могу реализовать. Абсолютно не понимаю.

Comment: Так а ваши попытки где? Где именно затык? Пока это звучит просто как "сделайте  за меня"

Comment: сейчас выложу свой нерабочий код

Comment: Так и в чем вопрос? Что конкретно не работает, что вы в вашем коде делаете?

Comment: В том, что пути выводятся некорректные, хотя код сделан в точности по алгоритму(вроде бы).

Comment: Тогда предоставьте входные данные, ожидаемые данные и полученные данные

Comment: Матрица смежности:
0 2 0 0
0 0 1 9
6 0 0 3
0 0 0 0
Вывод алгоритма: 0 2 1 3
Правильный вывод: 0 3 4 7

Comment: Вот несколько реализаций https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Gabow&type=

Comment: К сожалению, это не то. Нужен Gabow’s scaling algorithm for single-source shortest paths.

Comment: @Reality_is_illusion, как минимум ты не правильно используешь `priority_queue`... как минимум для первого цикла...

Comment: Поподробнее, пожалуйста) в чем ошибка?

Comment: @Reality_is_illusion, сложно сказать, что именно не так: просто какую-то херню с очередью творишь... как минимум, в очереди должны хранится индексы вершин, а сортироваться они должны по расстоянию, у тебя же там только расстояния... а ещё при обходе ребёр текущей вершины цикл должен быть только один... и ответ, очевидно, неправильный (или как он такой получается?)... Кстати, алгоритм, вообще говоря, рассчитан на работу со списками смежности (но это не суть).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если аккуратно переписать псевдокод из [вышеупомянутой статьи](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b4db/ebb43dbe4fd261a32f80f86f2f98b246a2eb.pdf) на С++, то получится нечто такое:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned vertex_t;
typedef unsigned dist_t;

size_t n;
int maxW(dist_t** g)
{
    dist_t max = g[0][0];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (g[i][j] > max)
            {
                max = g[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}

struct VertexPrio {
    vertex_t v;
    dist_t prio;

    bool operator<(const VertexPrio& other) const {
        return this->prio < other.prio;
    }
    bool operator>(const VertexPrio& other) const {
        return this->prio > other.prio;
    }
};

void Gabow(vertex_t s, dist_t** G) {
    vector <dist_t> dist(n,std::numeric_limits<dist_t>::max());
    unsigned i = log2(maxW(G));
    priority_queue <VertexPrio, std::vector<VertexPrio>, std::greater<VertexPrio>> q;
    dist[s] = 0;
    q.push(VertexPrio{s,0});

    while (!q.empty()) {
        vertex_t u = q.top().v;
        q.pop();

        for (vertex_t v = 0; v < n; v++) {
            if (G[u][v] != 0) {
                unsigned wi = G[u][v] >> i;
                if (dist[v] > dist[u] + wi) {
                    dist[v] = dist[u] + wi;
                    q.push(VertexPrio{v,dist[v]});
                }
            }
        }
    }

    while (i > 0)
    {
        i--;
        vector <dist_t> extradist(n, std::numeric_limits<dist_t>::max());
        extradist[s] = 0;
        priority_queue <VertexPrio, std::vector<VertexPrio>, std::greater<VertexPrio>> q;
        q.push(VertexPrio{s,0});
        while (!q.empty()) {
            vertex_t u = q.top().v;
            q.pop();

            for (vertex_t v = 0; v < n; v++) {
                if (G[u][v] != 0) {
                    unsigned wi = G[u][v] >> i;
                    int l = wi + 2 * (dist[u] - dist[v]);
                    if (extradist[v] > extradist[u] + l) {
                        extradist[v] = extradist[u] + l;
                        q.push(VertexPrio{v, extradist[v]});
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (vertex_t u = 0; u < n; u++) {
            if (dist[u] < std::numeric_limits<dist_t>::max()) {
                dist[u] = 2 * dist[u] + extradist[u];
            }
        }
    }

    for (vertex_t v = 0; v < n; v++) {
        cout << dist[v] << " ";
    }
    cout << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    ifstream infile("graph.txt");
    infile >> n;
    dist_t** mas = new dist_t*[n];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mas[i] = new dist_t[n];
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            infile >> mas[i][j];
        }
    }
    infile.close();

    Gabow(/*start=*/ 0,mas);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        delete[]mas[i];
    }
    delete[]mas;
    return 0;
}
```

---

> Правильный вывод: `0 3 4 7`

На самом деле правильный ответ: `0 2 3 6`

Comment: Да, с ответом я действительно ошибся) Все отлично работает, спасибо!